# How to show recylcer view items on app start when data comes from datastore?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, aws-amplify

I am using recylcer view on a fragment and fetching the data that to show on recycler view form datastore through query.I want to show the data on recycler view on opeing the app like youtube and instagram but I can't do that. When I add a button and put the recyler.setadapter in onClicklister it worked after the button clicked.But I want to do that on app start.If you are confused then look at the below code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
  apiQuery();
    adapter=new MyAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
private void apiQuery(){
    Amplify.API.query(
            ModelQuery.list(Todo.class, Todo.NAME.contains(" ")),
            response -> {
                for (Todo todo : response.getData()) {
                  arrayList.add(todo);
                    Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", todo.getName());
                }
            },
            error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Query failure", error)
    );
}
```

Comment: if you're using an api call, there's no way to get data immediately, unless you cache it in local storage, like sqlite

Comment: How youtube ,twitter,Instagram works? is there any souce to learn the things that you said.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the adapter in the button click method. You can preload the data on splash screen etc and save the data on device and then when your fragment/activity is loaded. You can set the adapter to load the data.

Comment: how to preload the data

Comment: I need more information about your database.

Comment: I am using aws amplify and graphQL api to store data.

Comment: yes you can load the data and save on device level on app start. Add a Loading/splash screen at start.

Comment: After using splash screen or loading where to call setAdapter method

Answer (score 0):

You have to send data to Adapter class after receiving response from API. Then update your recyclerview adapter's list and call notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Refer below sample code;

In Fragment

```
response -> {
                for (Todo todo : response.getData()) {
                  arrayList.add(todo);
                    Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", todo.getName());
                }
                adapter.updateData(arrayList)
            }
```

In Adapter class

```
fun updateData(list: ArrayList<Model>) {
    arraylist.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: nope bro when the loop completes that arraylist contains all items

Comment: Your activity list having all items in the sense how RecyclerView know new data updated, you are setting adapter before adding data to arraylist; I suggest you better go through RecyclerView documentation properly